# DELETE FROM multiple tables (Snowflake)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For the longest time I assumed that Snowflake SQL is patterned after MYSQL, but when I tried to do a DELETE statement to delete from multiple tables I got an error straightaway:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected 'DELETE'.

This is my DELETE statement to delete rows from two tables where the UPDATE_DATE is of a particular value:

```
DELETE worker_table, worker_history_table  
FROM worker_table t1 
inner JOIN worker_history_table t2  
   on TO_DATE(UPDATE_DATE) = TO_DATE(UPDATE_DATE) 
WHERE TO_DATE(t1.DW_UPDATE_DATE) = '2023-07-12'
```

Below is the MYSQL link showing how it is done - am I doing anything wrong?

[MySQL Delete From Multiple Tables](https://www.databasestar.com/sql-delete/#:%7E:text=To%20delete%20records%20from%20multiple,INNER%20JOIN%20table2%20ON%20table1)

```
DELETE table1, table2
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.field = table2.field
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: Given the founders where all ex-Oracle developers, it's probably best to assume it's Oracle patterned. I am super interested how/why you felt it was MySQL based, as this is a common statement, but I have not been able to find why people feel that.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim thank you for taking the time to read and update my post - as well as correcting my misconception that iSnowflake SQL != MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *For the longest time I assumed that Snowflake SQL is patterned after MYSQL*

Snowflake Data Cloud != MySQL

The assumption that Snowflake supports all language extensions from different dialects is simply incorrect.

[Standard and Extended SQL Support](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/intro-supported-features#standard-and-extended-sql-support)

> **Standard DML** such as UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT, as well as more advanced DML:
>
> - Multi-table INSERT, MERGE, and multi-merge.
> - DML for bulk data loading/unloading.

---

Assuming that both table have corresponding rows you could delete them from each table separately:

```
-- BEGIN TRAN;

DELETE FROM worker_table
WHERE TO_DATE(DW_UPDATE_DATE) = '2023-07-12';

DELETE FROM worker_history_table
WHERE TO_DATE(DW_UPDATE_DATE) = '2023-07-12';

-- COMMIT;
```

Comment: thank you - looks like Snowflake does not allow deleting rows in multiple tables within one delete statement.   I will do them separately then.    Could these be done in a stored procedure (though I am not well versed with stored procedure yet)?